# Unknown IP attempted access to UDP port

Tags: networking, security, firewall, anti-virus

I am checking up on my antivirus software (McAffee) and noticed in my security history it says: 
The PC 192.168.0.45 tried to access your system port UDP port 137. If you want to allow this traffic either trust the IP address or open the port in the system Services in Firewall.
UDP port 137 is commonly used by the "NETBIOS Name" service or program. NetBIOS is used for windows file sharing. It can be exploited to access files on your computer.
Your computer is being protected from this type of potential attack.
The source ip address is on your local network

I also have another warning coming from an ip address 192.168.0.254 but the last address in my router is 192.168.0.253 it is not in the list of devices on my router.

Comment: You implied that you were able to get a list of currently connected devices from your router, are you able to see what 192.168.0.45 is?

Comment: yes that is my roommate

Comment: So your question is about the 192.168.0.253, which you can't see in your router list?

Comment: yes the 254, but also is it normal to have the connection to .45 or do you think there is something suspicious? i also get many bad tcp connections to his "google nest mini"

Comment: If the .45 address is a PC, it's not entirely unusual. That PC is probably just seeing which other PCs are on the network for file sharing. And what do you mean by "bad TCP connections"?

Comment: it means they are highlighted in black and red in wireshark meaning this filter tcp.analysis.flags && !tcp.analysis.window_update